# Accessing State Id of fields React

Tags: reactjs

I set up a table full of values row by row. Each TextField that holds a data has a onChange method that triggers like this:

```
onChange={e => this.change(e, items.data[i].id)}
```

So when this happens

```
change(e,id) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
    //UpdateUser(id,e.target.name,e.target.value)
}
```

but the problem is that I need to do a PUT request, so inside UpdateUser, I need to get a hold of all other data not only what data changed and it's ID. So I am thinking I need to send the state ID. For example, state is in this format:

```
data: Array(2)
0: {id: 7, userId: 1, firm: "A", office: "003", salesCode: "123", …}
1: {id: 14, userId: 1, firm: "A", office: "050", salesCode: "051", …}
```

so inside change method, I want to send in the ID under the Data so I have access to other fields of the input to update those fields values as well.

For example, if user clicks the second element (id: 14), I need to send that full 1: array to the UpdateUser then I can submit all that information through the API. How can I do this?

Comment: Include the data as one more param. Try something like this `onChange={e => this.change(e, items.data, items.data[i].id)}`. Then the whole data is available in `onChange` method.

Comment: You're genius! Thank you, how did I miss this btw? haha

Comment: Another quick question though, for change method I have below how does it now which state to update? 
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })

Comment: I set states like this tableInfo: [{
                    id:null,
                    firm:null,
                    office:null,
                    salesCode:null,
                    account:null}],

Comment: I am unable to get that. For more clear on this, please create a codepen/sandbox with sample data and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here, I changed my code of below:

from

```
onChange={e => this.change(e, items.data, items.data[i].id)}
```

to

```
onChange={e => this.change(e, items.data, items.data[i])}
```

So I am sending all of the data and initial set up state for all of the data, I did like below

```
    [{ id:null,
       firm:null,
       office:null,
       salesCode:null,
       account:null}],
```